# Ember 2.3.0 requires a Beta version of Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js

I am in the process of embarking on my first Ember project. Reading the Ember Guides has left me a bit perplexed when it comes to selecting the version of Ember and Ember CLI appropriate for production use.

If I am reading the documentation correctly, Ember 2.3.0 is considered a production ready release build. The Guides also highly recommend using Ember CLI to create and develop an Ember application. However, the documentation says to install Ember CLI 2.2.0-beta.6. Looking at the Ember CLI site, I see that my choice for Ember 2.3.0 development appears to be Ember CLI 2.3.0-beta.1. I am confused since both of these Ember CLI versions are not production releases. In fact, the latest non-beta Ember CLI release is 1.13.15, which would set me back to Ember 1.13.12. Apparently, if I do some manual migration, I can use that version of the CLI with Ember 2.1.0. What do I need to do to use the latest released version of Ember 2 with a released version of the Ember CLI?

Comment: I would recommend to use the `2.2.0-beta.6`!
ember-cli is in some refactoring at the moment, and the situation is not optimal, but a beta build-tool is not soo bad. still you use production code for your productive environment! Manual migration is possible. Just edit your `package.json` and `bower.json`, but you may will run into trouble depending what you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2.x versions of Ember CLI are indeed betas, but they're production ready.

This was done because there are some important changes still being done, like addonifying Ember.js (Ember Data already went through that process), and others that might break backwards compatibility like the [final pods structure](https://speakerdeck.com/rwjblue/a-tale-of-two-pods). There will be a migration path for any breaking change to your application code, so don't let it scare you!

The betas are provided so people can more easily start a project with more up to date generators and dependencies.

The current recommendation is to `npm install -g ember-cli@beta` until a 2.x stable release comes out, at which time [the release](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases) will have the relevant upgrade instructions.

Update: Ember CLI 2.3 stable has been released, you can install it with `npm install -g ember-cli@2.3`, or the latest stable with `npm install -g ember-cli@latest`.

Comment: This summarizes the current situation well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough answer!